# Express and Nginx figthing over routing

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

So i have a strange configuration that i need until i get to refactor a project later this year.

it is a static index.html landing page served with a location root "/" by NGINX.

i have a slash location like so:

```
    location /channel/ {
        proxy_pass http://node_server:5000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Ssl on;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

that express.js then handles. Express just serves a static folder with auto-generated content that a user can then navigate around in.

It works well in the sense that any appending slashes like:

> /channel/open/

but ONLY if i have a trailing slash after "open". If i leave it out then NGINX will throw a "404 Not Found", if i keep it in, it works as intended.

The thing is that a user should be able to click on a folder in the static served directory to traverse a file structure, and the way that works in a browser is that it does not append a trailing slash to a directory name when clicked, so NGINX then throws the "404".I have tried a NPM package called 'express-slash' but that did not solve the issue.

i was hoping someone here had some suggestions on what i could try out next?

Answer (score 0):

Details about trailing slash behavior can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/607615/using-trailing-slashes-in-nginx-configuration

But if your goal is to configure NGINX to allow directory traversal, you may be looking for the `autoindex` directive: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html